# RSpec view spec failures after upgrading to Qt5 for capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

After I upgraded to Qt5, some of my previously passing specs started to fail. Some of the failures are related to unreliable outgoing requests. For example, in a spec I was checking if 10 requests have been made, and the spec would fail with only n requests made, n was sometimes 2 or 3 or another, unreliably. I tried changing Capybara's default wait time, but no luck.

Here is another simpler failure. It's checking if the url changed after clicking a link:

```rb
it 'shows sorting with correct link', js: true do
  expect(page).to have_content(/Sorted by/i)
  expect(page).to have_selector(:link_or_button, text: /Most Recent/i)
  page.find(:link_or_button, text: /A-Z/i).click
  expect(current_url).to include 'sort=name'
end
```

And it gave me the failure:

```
Failure/Error: expect(current_url).to include 'sort=name'
  expected "http://127.0.0.1:51355/shows" to include "sort=name"
```

I turned on capybara-webkit's debug mode, and it looked like it didn't actually write response to the new url:

```
(... previous logs ignored...)

Received "Node.leftClick"
Started "Node.leftClick"
Started request to "http://127.0.0.1:51355/shows?sort=name&status="
Finished "Node.leftClick" with response "Success()"
Wrote response true ""
Received "CurrentUrl()"
Started "CurrentUrl()"
Finished "CurrentUrl()" with response "Success(http://127.0.0.1:51355/shows)"
Wrote response true "http://127.0.0.1:51355/shows"
Received 200 from "http://127.0.0.1:51355/shows?sort=name&status="
Received "Reset()"
Started "Reset()"
Finished "Reset()" with response "Success()"
Wrote response true ""
Received "EnableLogging()"
Started "EnableLogging()"
Finished "EnableLogging()" with response "Success()"
Wrote response true ""
Received "SetUnknownUrlMode(block)"
Started "SetUnknownUrlMode(block)"
Finished "SetUnknownUrlMode(block)" with response "Success()"
Wrote response true ""
Received "SetTimeout(300)"
Started "SetTimeout(300)"
Finished "SetTimeout(300)" with response "Success()"
Wrote response true ""
        shows sorting with correct link (FAILED - 1)
```

I wonder if anyone has experienced similar failures or how I can further investigate this issue. The specs were passing with capybara-webkit built with Qt4 but not sure why they failed with Qt5. More info about my setup:

```
capybara (2.7.0)
capybara-webkit (1.10.1)
rails (4.2.5.1)
rspec (3.3)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actions are not guaranteed to be synchronous when using Capybara, which means you need to use the matchers provided by Capybara that will wait/retry for a little bit.  In the case of your `expect(current_url).to include 'sort=name'` example that should be written as

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(/sort=name/)
```

For your "number of requests made" spec we'd need to see code.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! Using Capybara matcher solved this spec. Regarding the "number of requests made" spec, I think capybara-webkit is [caching requests](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/724) now. After I append random query string to the url, it behaves as expected. Not sure how I can address this tho, or disable browser caching. I certainly don't want to change the actual code because of that. You have any thoughts?

Comment: @322896 Sorry - no idea on how solve that, other than random query strings only added when test mode - although if you really need the number of requests to be made in production then you'd need something to bust the cache anyway.

Comment: Yea thanks. Maybe I have to make the specs more realistic or get a way around it.